# Set Width without Shifting

Tags: css, html, position, fixed

When I use

```
position:fixed;
left:10px;
right:10px;
```

it shifts the box to the right instead of making it narrower.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are not defining the width here. You are just setting where it  should render

Comment: Please provide a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) with *all* relevant code ..

Answer (score 1):

when you defined a fixed element's width,
then you set both left and right of it, you can't change it's width, and only the after one of left and width can take effect.

in your case, you should put a wraper out of the box and set the wraper's css to

```
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
```

then insert a inner box into this wraper with css

```
padding: 0 10px;
```

Comment: But I didn't define its width.

Comment: or your fixed element's width has been calculated automatically according to it's content